# replace duplicate values after first ocurrence in a column mantaining the rows

Tags: pandas

I have the following df with lots of rows:

```
    xx   yy   zz
A   5    4   'd.1'
B   2    2   'd.1'
C   1    1   'e.1'
D   2    2   'e.2'
E   1    5   'e.2'
.
```

I would like to remove all the duplicate values (keeping the rows) after the first value in column zz in order to obtain the following output:

```
    xx   yy   zz
A   5    4   'd.1'
B   2    2   '0.0'   
C   1    1   'e.1'
D   2    2   'e.2'
E   1    5   '0.0'
```

How could I get this done?
    .
    .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC this is what you need.

```
df['zz']=np.where(df['zz'].duplicated(), '0.0',df['zz'])
```

Answer (score 1):

There is special function to do that `drop_duplicates`

```
df = df.drop_duplicates(subset='zz', keep='first')
```

**Update:** Do you need to drop duplicates in column `zz` only?

```
df.zz.loc[df.zz == df.zz.shift()] = '0.0'
```

Comment: I would like to keep the rows where the duplicate exists

Comment: I think he only wants to make the duplicate values as `0.0` only in that column.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this is the pandas way to do that.

```
df.loc[df.zz == df.zz.shift(), 'zz'] = 0
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use:

```
is_duplicate = df.apply(df['zz'].duplicated(), axis=1)
df.where(~is_duplicate, '0.0')
```

Comment: outputs: ('The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().', 'occurred at index A')